# delphi txmldata to string

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I have a soap call that returns a txmldata as a result. I used WDSL importer to get the methods and the function i am using is defined as:

```
function ERP_Inventario_Exp_1(const pToken: string; const pApp_Version: string): ERP_Inventario_Exp_1Result; stdcall;
```

ERP_Inventario_Exp_1Result is defined as:

```
ERP_Venta_Exp_1Result = class(TRemotable)
private
  Fschema: TXMLData;
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property schema: TXMLData  Index (IS_REF) read Fschema write Fschema;
end;
```

So it appears to me it returns a `txmldata`.  I am trying to take that response and save the xml from it to a file or string.  On here in another thread it said to use `txmldata.xml.xmlnode.xml` but that appears to return the structure only not the actual data.

Any pointers ?

Comment: No, it's returning an instance of `ERP_Venta_Exp1Result`, which is an object of type `TRemotable` that has a property `schema`. You would read from that schema, retrieving the parts of it that are relevant.

Comment: Ok, Any idea how to read from that schema to get the actual sales data sinc e  all I see is schema like field definitions not data.